# How to create PDF file links with relative file path and PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink, relative-path, pdfsharp

My App creates a Content.pdf file that links to Server.pdf and Client.pdf. This is the folder structure:

- ..\MyApp\Ressources\Content.pdf
- ..\MyApp\Ressources\Server\Server.pdf
- ..\MyApp\Ressources\Client\Client.pdf

Furthermore, the folders and files get burned on a CD/DVD or get backed up on a network drive - that causes me to use relative file paths. I use following code to create the Content.pdf:

relative WebLink:

```
var relativeFileLinkPath =  "./" + Directory.GetParent(doc.Uri.LocalPath).Name + "/"+ doc.OutputFileName;
page.AddWebLink(pdfrect, relativeFileLinkPath);
```

relative FileLink:

```
var relativeFileLinkPath =  "./" + Directory.GetParent(doc.Uri.LocalPath).Name + "/"+ doc.OutputFileName;
page.AddFileLink(pdfrect, relativeFileLinkPath);
```

Both work fine on local drive, but my issues are:

- WebLinks do not work/open on network drive
- FileLinks close the Content.pdf and replace it with the linked pdf file

**Questions:**

*How can I modify the FileLinks to get opened in a new (PDF reader) instance/window?*

- Holding the CTRL-Key when clicking on the FileLink is an option but not a nice solution.

*What’s the right syntax for relative PDF web links?*

Answer (score 0):

`AddFileLink` is the correct method for files sitting side by side in a folder.

To control whether a new window will be opened, a small modification of PDFsharp's PdfLinkAnnotation class will be needed. PDF supports a `NewWindow` attribute which PDFsharp cannot currently set.

Get the source for PDFsharp, locate `"<</Type/Action/S/Launch/F<</Type/Filespec/F{0}>> >>"` in PdfLinkAnnotation.cs and replace it with `"<</Type/Action/S/Launch/NewWindow true/F<</Type/Filespec/F{0}>> >>"`.

Disclaimer: I did not test the proposed change - I hope it is syntactically correct and I hope it does what you want.
Disclaimer 2: This change is needed for PDFsharp 1.50 beta 3. Later versions may have support for that flag.

Comment: I added PDFSharp to my WPF App through the Reference Manager. ( `packages\PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF.1.32.2608.0` ) Do i have to remove the package and add it manually or is there another option?